# Choosing name of column in entity framework code-first migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have seen similar questions to this; but none quite the same; and none have helped me. I want the migration to use a different name for the column than I have for the property in my class. On built-in types, I am able to do this with `[Column("newName")]`. However, this doesn't work when I want a foreign key to another class.

In other words, this works just fine:

```
[Column("NameInDB")]
public string NameInCode { get; set; }
```

But this doesn't work at all:

```
[Column("Employee_Id")]
public virtual Employee Owner { get; set; }
```

In the second case, the migration still creates the column as Owner_Id; it completely ignores the Column annotation. Is there somewhere that it says that the Column annotation only works for built-in types? I couldn't find anything about that.

I know that it is possible to use the `[ForeignKey]` annotation to do this, but if I do, I have to have an extra property in my code that I don't want:

```
[ForeignKey("Employee_Id")]
public virtual Employee Owner { get; set; }

public int Employee_Id { get; set; }
```

I don't want to do that because the Employee_Id property is redundant in that case; I'd rather just use the Owner property. Is there a way around this, or a good reason that `[Column]` seems to be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

`public virtual Employee Owner { get; set; }`  is not mapped to DB, it is not represented in database. It populated by Entity Framework automatically for your convenience. Employee_Id - this is what is stored in DB. Entity Framework uses Employee_Id field to create Owner object. So, Emplyee_Id is not redundant in that case, it is mandatory and it has physical representation in DB, but Owner field is logical part of the class, managed by Entity Framework and not have it's column in DB. Makes sense?

Comment: That makes some sense; except that all my class relationships have only the parent class instance as a property, and not also an int (ID) property. Like, Employee has a Company property that's an instance of  the Company class. I don't have any Company_Id property; EF seems to be mapping it to Company_Id in the database anyway.